# How to understand CSS calc with responsive font-size? This code does not seem to accurately reflect max viewport width, thus font-size is too small

Tags: html, css

Css calc does not seem to be picking up on the max viewport size, and thus my font size is too small (not `1rem` ) at the set `maximum viewport width` of `1400px`. No matter what I do with the browser size the font increases in size. I would have thought that at `1400px` `viewport width` the font would display at `1rem` and then decrease in size from there, but it's not 1rem at `1400px` wide it's showing as smaller, so I'm not sure how to control this as it's not doing what I think it should be doing.

What am I not understanding? How do I get this code to show max font size of 1rem at `1400px` width of the `browser window`, and progressively shrinking to `0.65rem` at a viewport size of `375px`?

My understanding of the following calc function is as follows: `calc([minimum size] + ([maximum size] - [minimum size]) * ((100vw - [minimum viewport width]) / ([maximum viewport width] - [minimum viewport width])));`. This is from the [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/fluid-typography/) website.

Here's my test code (here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SquareGiraffe/k68bdqLh/) if that's easier to see what's going on).

```css
.testok{
     font-size: calc(0.65rem + (1 - 0.65) * ((100vw - 375px) / (1400 - 375)));
}
```

```html
<p class="testok">Le petit chien marron....</p>
```

Comment: Maybe use a different approach and use [clamp()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp) to achieve a min- and max-size.

Comment: at 1400px you will get `.65rem + (1-0.65)*1px` .. the article is using px and not rem. You cannot get rem values with such equation. The rem will get turned to px based on the font-size defined on the root element

Comment: @TemaniAfif I think you've provided the answer actually, as to why Calc is not working for me. √  :)  Using px this works great, it's just not limited in it's expansion

Comment: @cloned and I think you've provided the answer to my actual problem. √ :). I found this `https://css-tricks.com/linearly-scale-font-size-with-css-clamp-based-on-the-viewport/`, it was difficult to understand and get the math right, but once I did I had it working like a charm.